# Rails - how to show :Confirm Modal with redirect_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Rails, using ActiveAdmin, trying to warn users that some data might be missing.

--Not by using model validations--

I just need a modal that makes user acknowledge (by clicking 'OK' or 'Cancel') that some fields are missing, but can still submit the form. I have *similar* boiler-plate working code elsewhere that looks something like:

```
text_node link_to "Delete", admin_gath_line_app_permit_path(permit), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }
```

I'm trying to bring that same :confirm modal magic to my 'def create' with this non-working bit of code:

```
def create
  create! do |format|
    if resource.errors.present?
      return render :edit
    else
      if !resource.GL_Permit.present?
        format.html { redirect_to admin_gath_lines_path(), :data => {:confirm =  "what about the GL Permit?" }}
      else
        resource.reload
        format.html { redirect_to admin_gath_lines_path() }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223696/how-do-i-redirect-to-open-a-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
def create
create! do |format|
if resource.errors.present?
  return render :edit
else
  if !resource.GL_Permit.present?
    format.html { redirect_to admin_gath_lines_path(), alert: "ALERT, WARNING"}
  else
    resource.reload
    format.html { redirect_to admin_gath_lines_path() }
  end
end
```

end
end